# AWS Throttling and Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am using `nodemailer` and `nodemailer-ses-transport`.

```
var nodemailer = require( 'nodemailer' );
var sesTransport = require( 'nodemailer-ses-transport' );
```

I am having to send out a couple thousand e-mails (telling inactive users to update their profiles, basically.) I am running into a throttling error, basically. Specifically I am hitting my `rateLimit`. I have been going off of this, although this isn't using `nodemailer-ses-transport`: https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/

Here are my transporter settings (I have tried both `rateLimit` and `sendingRate` but neither seem to work - I still end up capping out):

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( sesTransport( {
            accessKeyId: secrets.awsAccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: secrets.awsSecretAccessKey,
            rateLimit: 5,
            region: 'us-west-2'
        } ) );
```

Also, my rate limit in AWS is set at 14.

Comment: apparently you are in sandbox mode.

Comment: *"I still end up capping out"*  Show specific error responses, please.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nodemailer-ses-transport package. Just set the sendingRate and then use sendMail as normal.

```
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: { ses, aws },
  sendingRate: 14,
});

const params = {
  from: 'EMAIL',
  to: 'EMAIL',
  subject: 'Message',
  html: 'I hope this <b>message</b> gets sent!',
  text: 'I hope this message gets sent!',
  // attachments: [{ filename: 'card.pdf', content: data, contentType: 'application/pdf' }],
};

transporter.sendMail(params, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
  console.log(info.envelope);
  console.log(info.messageId);
});
```

Important thing to note here, nodemailer waits for the next second to continue with the next batch of throttled emails and the next and so on. So if you are running a script that exits immediately after calling the last sendMail(), the throttled emails will never get sent. Make sure the process runs until all emails are sent by listening to on idle or use settimeout.